# BLANK ROW starting from D7

Tags: excel, vba, row

I know that i can find first blank row in MS Excel (VBA) with this code:

```
blank_row = Sheets("REPORT").range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
```

But how to find blank row but from `D7` - in other words I want to `rows.count` skip first six rows and start from seven row..

Comment: This method only finds the first blank row if the data before it is contiguous.  I think you want a different method since it seems that you have blanks within your data

Comment: blank_row = Sheets("REPORT").range("D7").End(xlUp).row or  blank_row = Sheets("REPORT").range("D7").End(xldown).row?

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets("REPORT").range("D7").End(xlDown).row + 1`

Though you may need to be careful if there is nothing in column D or D7 is the only filled cell you'll have to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the Blank Row Starting from D7 then you have to do with below

```
Sheets("REPORT").Range("D7").End(xlDown).Row + 1 'returns the row number

Sheets("REPORT").Range("D7").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select ' to Select the Blank row
```